# Получить уникальные ключи из массива с объектами

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Имеется массив с объектами `someData`. Мне необходимо получить в таком виде как в коде `result`, без изменения исходного массива. Я начал делать через map, но не уверен что это правильный подход. В результирующем массиве значение ключей val1, val2... не нужно. Необходимо именно название уникальных ключей из массива `someData`. При этом количество ключей может УВЕЛИЧИВАТЬСЯ - val4, val5... => нужно получать все уникальные ключи. P.S. При этом ключ `name` получать не нжуно

```js
let someData = [
    {
      name: 'class 1',
      val1:  56,
      val2:  21,
      val3: 32,
    },
    {
      name: 'class 2',
      val1: 41,
      val2: 15,
      val3: 78,
    },
    {
      name: 'class 3',
      val1: 56,
      val2: 70,
      val3: 43,
      }
    ]
    
    //необходимый результат
      const result  = [
      { key: 'val1', title: 'val1', value: 0},
      { key: 'val2', title: 'val2', value: 0},
      { key: 'val3', title: 'val3', value: 0},
     ]
     
     //мой недоконченный вариант
    const result = someData.map((item, index, arr) => {
      return {
        key: '???',
        title: '??',
        value: 0
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если честно, я не совсем въехал в вашу задачу. Но может эта строка кода поможет вам найти нужное решение.

```js
let someData = [{
    name: 'class 1',
    val1: 56,
    val2: 21,
    val3: 32,
  },
  {
    name: 'class 2',
    val1: 41,
    val2: 15,
    val3: 78,
  },
  {
    name: 'class 3',
    val1: 56,
    val2: 70,
    val3: 43,
  }
]

result = [...new Set(someData.map(obj => Object.keys(obj)).flat())]
            .filter(name => 'name' !== name) 
            .map(name => ({key: name, title: name, value: 0}));
console.log(result);
```

Конструкция `[... <data> ]` превращает `<data>` любого **итерируемого** типа в массив.

Конструкция `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]].flat()` делает массив такого вида `[1,2,3,1,2,3]`.

Конструкция `[...new Set([1,2,3,1,2,3])]` возвратит массив уникальных значений `[1,2,3]`.

Конструкцию `someData.map(obj => Object.keys(obj)).flat()` разумно заменить на `someData.flatMap(obj => Object.keys(obj))`. Как заметил в комментариях @Grundy:
`.map()` `+` `.flat()` `=>` [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: А как-нибудь возможно исключить 
 {
    "key": "name",
    "title": "name",
    "value": 0
  } ?

Comment: @AzetX добавил фильтр

Comment: Спасибо большое) Сейчас буду разбираться тогда

Comment: @AzetX сделал некоторые уточнения

Comment: _Конструкция `[... <data> ]` превращает <data> любого типа в массив._ - совсем не любого, а в некоторых случаях вообще ошибка будет

Comment: `map + flat` => [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: @Grundy, про тип исправил, по `flatMap()`, если честно, метод на любителя.

Comment: если один метод делает то же самое что и два, лучше использовать один